# How to theme elgg with HTML and CSS only?

Tags: php, html, css, elgg

I just installed elgg (http://elgg.org) into my site and custom theming it is so hard.

I have the theme all coded out in html and css. But Elgg is split up into all these different php files its too confusing.

Is there a theme or tutorial out there that could help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the tutorial at [Elgg Themes](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Themes). And also, some [example theme plugins](http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/category/themes). 
They recommend to develop themes as a plugin instead of changing the code of existing theme.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Krishna's suggestion, an easy way to get started learning Elgg theming is to install [the EasyTheme plugin](http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/juBo/read/801723?release=822693), which is designed to be a simple way to create your own theme with simple CSS.  I am using EasyTheme as the basis for creating an Elgg site to match an existing website, and so far it has been very easy to work with and get the needed results.